# i am getting null data when i get the data from xml nodes

Tags: java, web-services

I'm receiving 'null' values when I try to read values from XML nodes.

Structure example:

`<document>
   <user>ss</user>
   <password >ssss</password >
 </document>`

> Result: o/p [user: null] [password: null]

This is my code:

```
public class stres() {  
   public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
      try {
         String resulturl ="my url";

         DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
         DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

         Document doc = db.parse(resulturl);

         NodeList documentt = doc.getElementsByTagName("document");     

         for (int i = 0; i < documentt.getLength(); i++) {
            Element data = (Element) documentt.item(0);
            Node user = data.getElementsByTagName("user").item(0);
            Node password = data.getElementsByTagName("password").item(0);

         }
      }
      catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please please format that code.

Comment: here is  my xml code
    
    
    <document>
    <user>ss</user>
    <password >ssss</password >
    
    
    </document>
    
    
    
    o/p
    
    [user: null]
    [password: null]

Comment: First make sure that the xml is getting loaded. You can get it by System.out.println(doc.getDocumentElement().getTextContent());

Comment: ..i tried that way shubham im getting o/p like this          O/P:   N17 ssivFspre univv>pre univv>rgs  .

Comment: NodeList documentt = doc.getElementsByTagName("document"); 
               System.out.println("documenttttttttttttttttttttttttttt"+documentt);        o/p :com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeepNodeListImpl@243e0b62